# How km column is computed in osm2po output table

Tags: postgis, osm2po

I've generated **hh_2po_4pgr** table using **osm2po** utility. Now I want to add a few extra edges by hands because some important points are missing from source osm data. In order to do this I need to compute **km** column. But the problem is that I was unable to guess the function that they use to produce this value.

Example: For **x1**=28.7075708 **y1**=55.4504115 **x2**=28.6814325 **y2**=55.4514459 they've got **km**=1.6939924

I've tryed following **postgis** functions:
1) st_distance

```
select ST_Distance(ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(55.4504115 28.7075708)'::geometry, 3857),
                   ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(55.4514459 28.6814325)'::geometry, 3857))/1000
```

which gives distance 3.319061442480019 km.

2) st_distancesphere

```
select ST_Distancesphere(ST_Makepoint(55.4504115, 28.7075708), ST_Makepoint(55.4514459, 28.6814325))/1000
```

which gives distance 2.9082010619 km.

So none of those are used by **osm2po**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostGIS coordinates are expressed as longitude first, then latitude.

After swapping the coordinates, the computed distance is close to what you have

```
 select ST_Distancesphere(ST_Makepoint(28.7075708,  55.4504115), ST_Makepoint(28.6814325,  55.4514459))/1000;
   ?column?
---------------
 1.65229073298
```

PS: never ever compute distances in 3857, the distorition is huge, almost by 50% at such latitude.

Comment: demmit, so simple... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If it is lines, then it should be ST_Length instead of just distance from start point to end point.

```
SELECT ST_Length(geometry_column::geography)/1000;
```

Casted to geography to get length in meters.